# How to extract a portion of this URL in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

Given this URL: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pnEX1OQXXXHzu6z9dPV5ZZ5VHqPU--6/view?usp=share_link`, how can I extract only what is between `d/` and `/view`?

I've tried it using: `=MID(A2,SEARCH("d/",A2)+1,SEARCH("/view",A2)-SEARCH("/view",A2)-1)+0`, but it doesn't work.

Here is a practical [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing), should you feel like killing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Regular Expressions in Google Sheets. The formula

`=REGEXEXTRACT("link text here", "d/(.+)/view")`

will make the cell value whatever is inside the matching group (whatever is in between "d/" and "/view".

Here is the documentation for Google Sheet's RegEx commands: [https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244'](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244%27)

You can learn more about Regular Expressions by playtesting with it here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: Relatively simple, but ```REGEX()``` is another world I am still to visit. Thanks!